# jQuery: What to do with the list that sortable('serialize') returns?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable, serialization

With jQuery I'm retrieving positions of a sortable list using 'serialize', like this:

`var order = $('ul').sortable('serialize');`

The variable 'order' then receives the following:

`id[]=2&id[]=3&id[]=1&id[]=4&id[]=5`

Now how can I use this data in an ajax call?

This is how I plan to do it, but it's ugly and I can't change the parameter name 'id':

`$.post('ajax.php?'+order,{action:'updateOrder'});`

Maybe I need to unserialize, then implode the variable 'order' and assign it to just one parameter?

---

I don't have a problem with the server side code, but I have a problem with the jQuery client site code. The question is, where do I place the 'order' variable in the script?

In the example I gave I added it as a query string:

`'ajax.php?'+order`

But I would like to pass it as a parameter, just like the action parameter. The following doesn't work, it returns a syntax error:

`$.post('ajax.php?'+order,{action:'updateOrder',order});`

Comment: Both your ideas will do. It depends on your mood :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found it! I needed to add the option `key:'string'` which changes the variable name to 'string' instead of 'id'.

```
var order = $('#projects ul').sortable('serialize',{key:'string'});

$.post('ajax.php',order+'&action=updateOrder');
```

Comment: Check out the answer with 'toArray'. It is also a really good option. http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-toArray

Answer (score 14):

I think the best way is not to use `sortable('serialize')` at all, but use jQuery to simply iterate over the sorted ids, like so:

```
order = [];
$('ul').children('li').each(function(idx, elm) {
  order.push(elm.id.split('_')[1])
});                                     
$.get('ajax.php', {action: 'updateOrder', 'order[]': order});
```

This has an advantage over explicitly appending the serialized sortable to the URL (or a parameter) in that it doesn't include the `order[]` parameter at all if there are no `li` in the list.  (When I had this problem I was using `sortable(connectWith: 'ul')` so it was entirely possible for a user to drag all the `li` from one list).  In contrast appending the serialized sortable would leave an unwanted '&'.

Comment: Thank you, this approach worked for my issue of trying to not pass it as part of the URL.

Comment: This seems like a more subtle approach.

Comment: Honestly, I wasted a lot of time trying to figure out how to use serialize. This approach makes way more sense to me and worked without all the trial and error I was going through.

Answer (score 7):

Lets say you were ordering news items, and your page sent this to "?id[]=2&id[]=3&id[]=1&id[]=4&id[]=5" your php code.

```
$_POST['id'] # would be [2,3,1,4,5]

// Now we need to update the position field of these items    

foreach($_POST['id'] as $i=>$id ):
   // For our first record, $i is 0, and $id is 2.

   $post = Post::get($id); # Do you own database access here
   $post->position = $i; # Set the position to its location in the array
   $post->save(); # Save the record
endforeach
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var order = $('#projects ul').sortable('toArray'});
```

this might work too ;)

Comment: This is a good option for what you want... iterate over the array and pass in the variable name as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is know to use var `order = $('ul').sortable('serialize');` feature is shown in the following link :

https://web.archive.org/web/20160701121834/http://blog.arnaud-k.fr/2010/09/29/tutorial-jquery-trier-une-liste-en-dragndrop-avec-jqueryui-sortable/

All you need to get the ordered list data in your php file is the code :

```
foreach( $_POST['id'] as $order => $order_nb )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Summarising to save clicks: the linked solution, on the client side, is to use the "update" callback (as in [Ata ul Mustafa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27700455/11966865)) and just do `$.post('ajax.php',order);`.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the "key" param I used the square brackets in order to get an array.

```
var data = $('#cms-form').serialize();
data += '&' + $('.ui-tabs-nav').sortable('serialize', {key:'nav_order[]'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution

I have created my own solution by manipulating sortable('serialize'). I have simplified it by using jquery functions, and then posted it to php url for updating order of list in the database. Have a look at my code.

```
$( "#covercast_sortable" ).sortable({
        update : function () { 
            var order = $('#covercast_sortable').sortable('serialize',{key:'string'}); 
            // order var gives something like string=3&string=2&string=1
            var ar = order.split('&');
            var i = 0;
            var str = '';
            for(i;i<ar.length;i++){
                if(str != "") { str += ','; }
                // slice is used to remove 'sting=' from every value of var ar
                str += ar[i].slice(7);
            }
            // here value of str is 3,2,1 with respect to order variable
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'myURL.php',
                data: 'order=' + str,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

if data is

`$data = 'album[]=stat&sort[]=157204&sort[]=157205&sort[]=157206&sort[]=157208&sort[]=157207&sort[]=157209&sort[]=157210&sort[]=157211&sort[]=157212&sort[]=157213';`

and you want to get sort as array in php 
 use [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)
`parse_str($data, $output);`
`print_r($output);`

**Output :** 
Array
(
    [album] => Array
        (
            [0] => stat
        )

```
[sort] => Array
    (
        [0] => 157204
        [1] => 157205
        [2] => 157206
        [3] => 157208
        [4] => 157207
        [5] => 157209
        [6] => 157210
        [7] => 157211
        [8] => 157212
        [9] => 157213
    )
```

)