# jQuery: How to reverse sortable('serialize') arrays from last to first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, serialization

The discussion begins [jQuery: What to do with the list that sortable('serialize') returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654535/jquery-what-to-do-with-the-list-that-sortableserialize-returns/2920760#2920760)

How to reverse it from last to first, updateList.php?id[]=5&id[]=4&id[]=3&id[]=2&id[]=1&&action=update?

```
<ul>
<li id="oreder-5">5</li>
<li id="oreder-4">4</li>
<li id="oreder-3">3</li>
<li id="oreder-2">2</li>
<li id="oreder-1">1</li>
<ul>
```

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    order=[];
    $('#list ul').children('li').each(function(idx, elm) { order.push(elm.id.split('-')[1]) });
    $.post('updateList.php', {'order[]': order, action: 'update'});

    function slideout(){
        setTimeout(function(){ $("#response").slideUp("slow", function () {}); }, 2000);
    }
    $("#response").hide();
 $(function() {
    $("#list ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.8, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
   var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=update'; 
   $.post("updateList.php", order, function(theResponse){
    $("#response").html(theResponse);
    $("#response").slideDown('slow');
    slideout();
   });
    }});             
 });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do it:

```
var reversed = $(this).sortable("serialize").split("&").reverse().join("&");
var order = reversed + '&action=update';
```

In other words:

- [Split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) the string at the '&'.
- [Reverse](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp) the resulting array.
- [Join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) the array with the '&' character to form the reversed serialized string.

Comment: Thanks, @karim79!
It works well for second jquery part with cursor:'move' effect, but does not work for 
order=[];
$('#list ul').children('li').each(function(idx, elm) { order.push(elm.id.split('-')[1]) });
$.post('updateList.php', {'order[]': order, action: 'update'});

Could you please get solution also for that!?

Answer (score 1):

Needed order.reverse(); before  $.post(..);