# How do I get the data from jquery ui's .sortable()?

Tags: php, jquery

This is my code:

```
$(".img-line").sortable({
   update:function(){
      var order = $('.img-line').sortable('serialize');
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         data: order,
         url: '/ajax/imageSort.php'
      });
      return false;
   }
});
```

And in my imageSort.php when I try to get the data, looking for it in $_GET or $_POST, they are all empty. How do I get the data the sortable() sends?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654535/jquery-what-to-do-with-the-list-that-sortableserialize-returns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You LI should have id.
The the jqueryui [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize). It is explain

> If serialize returns an empty string,
>   make sure the id attributes include an
>   underscore. They must be in the form:
>   "set_number" For example, a 3 element
>   list with id attributes foo_1, foo_5,
>   foo_2 will serialize to
>   foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2. You can use
>   an underscore, equal sign or hyphen to
>   separate the set and number. For
>   example foo=1 or foo-1 or foo_1 all
>   serialize to foo[]=1.

Answer (score 1):

You must have IDs on your li items like...

```
<ul>
    <li id="item_1"> item 1 </li>
    <li id="item_2"> item 2 </li>
    <li id="item_3"> item 3 </li>
</ul>
```

then when you `$('.img-line').sortable('serialize');` it will post and array of `item[]`

so with PHP for example you could do:

```
$items = $_POST["item"];
foreach($items as $item => $value){
    // do somthing
}
```