# Need instruction for beginner with sortable and serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

You can find exemples everywhere about how to make a list sortable. But then, I need to post the new order to another page.I must oversee something stupid but after having passed 3 days on it I still don't have the solution.
I have an query output

Then the jquery code

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#ulsortable" ).sortable();

    });
        $('#frm-sort').submit(function(){
            var sort_serialized = $("#ulsortable").sortable("serialize");
        });
    </script>

    <form action="#request.site.webroot#/actions/act_writeneworder.cfm" method="post" id="frm-sort">
  <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="save" />
  <input type="hidden" name="sort_serialized" id="sort_serialized" value="" />
</form>
```

The variable sort_serialized however gives an empty string. This is my first experience with jQuery. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Bianca

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:coldfusion]?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for serialize](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize):

> Serializes the sortable's item id's into a form/ajax submittable string. Calling this method produces a hash that can be appended to any url to easily submit a new item order back to the server.
>
> It works by default by looking at the id of each item in the format 'setname_number', and it spits out a hash like "setname[]=number&setname[]=number".
>
> You can also give in a option hash as second argument to custom define how the function works. The possible options are: 'key' (replaces part1[] with whatever you want), 'attribute' (test another attribute than 'id') and 'expression' (use your own regexp).
>
> If serialize returns an empty string, make sure the id attributes include an underscore. They must be in the form: "set_number" For example, a 3 element list with id attributes foo_1, foo_5, foo_2 will serialize to foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2. You can use an underscore, equal sign or hyphen to separate the set and number. For example foo=1 or foo-1 or foo_1 all serialize to foo[]=1.

Do you have `id` attributes on your list items?

Have you verified all of them contain an underscore and are of the correct form?

Comment: I am not sure I understand eveerything you just said. For your question, all list items have an unique ID that is the id they have in the database. <li id="ID_#T_items_autoID#"> which results in id=ID_12345 etc.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the contents of the `#ulsortable` element? It would probably be easiest to explain the issue in the context of your source code.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a variable = to the serailization, but not the actual hidden field, what happens if you set the hidden field value using

```
$("#sort_serialized").val($("#ulsortable").sortable("serialize").toString());
```

also here is a question that has more information about posting a serialized list to another page that may be useful.

[jQuery: What to do with the list that sortable('serialize') returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654535/jquery-what-to-do-with-the-list-that-sortableserialize-returns)

------------------ Here is an Example for you that works ---------------------------

You should be able to post this in an html page, adjust your Script and Style Refereneces in the head and it will work.  When you click the button it will put the serialized list in the textbox.  For example after moving a couple of Items, I get the result

> Item[]=1&Item[]=4&Item[]=2&Item[]=3

Here is the code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head>
     <title>Sample Sort and Serialize</title>
<link href="Content/Css/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Content/Scripts/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="Content/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <form>
     <script language="javascript">
         $(function() {
             $("#ulSortable").sortable();
             $("#ulSortable li").addClass("ui-widget-header");

             $('#btnSort').click(function() {
                 $("#sort_serialized").val($("#ulSortable").sortable("serialize").toString());
        });
    });
   </script> 
   <style>
         #ulSortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
         #ulSortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; cursor: pointer;}
         #ulSortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
   </style>

     <ul id="ulSortable">
         <li id="Item_1">Item 1 Content</li>
         <li id="Item_2">Item 2 Content</li>
         <li id="Item_3">Item 3 Content</li>
         <li id="Item_4">Item 4 Content</li>
     </ul>
     <br /><br />           

     <input type="text" id="sort_serialized" size="50"/>
     <input type="button" id="btnSort" value="Sort List" />

</form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I tried both
    $("#sort_serialized") = $("#ulsortable").sortable("serialize"); AND 
    var sort_serialized = $('ulsortable').sortable('serialize');

Then in the next page i do a dump of the variable sort_serialized and it keeps saying it is an empty string. All list items do have an ID. I feel completely lost.

Comment: There, I added a code sample with a simple sortable list and a button that puts the serialized list in the textbox. Hope this helps.